# start an activity through selecting item in a spinner

Tags: android, android-activity, spinner

I have a spinner where the user enters items dynamically.
I want when the user selects an item from spinner to start another activity.

I use:

```
  ...
  m_myDynamicSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.myspinner);
  m_addItemText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextItem);
  Button addButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add);
  Button removeButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.remove);

  m_adapterForSpinner = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
  m_adapterForSpinner.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
  m_myDynamicSpinner.setAdapter(m_adapterForSpinner);
  m_adapterForSpinner.add("Items List");

 ....

  }
 private void addNewSpinnerItem() {
     CharSequence textHolder = "" + m_addItemText.getText();
     m_adapterForSpinner.add(textHolder);
     }

     private void clearSpinnerItems() {
     m_adapterForSpinner.clear();
     m_adapterForSpinner.add("Items List");
     }
     public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

     public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
     View view, int pos, long id) {

     m_addItemText.setText((CharSequence)parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString());

     if (pos == 1){
         Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, selection.class);
         MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
     }

     }
```

but nothing happens.

Comment: Have you verified that `pos == 1` returns `true` or did you mean to have `pos == 0`? Is `selection` an `Activity` in your `manifest`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to you code

```
m_myDynamicSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
```

Hope this helped you.

Comment: :Hello, this works!But at the edittext field it shows "Items List".Can I do sth for not showing this?Thanks!

Comment: Comment this line(or remove it) `m_addItemText.setText((CharSequence)parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString());`

Comment: :I totally forgot that!Thanks@ (if you can help with this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526110/save-gps-location-from-onmylocationchange-function-which-is-inside-onmylocatio).Thanks