# save gps location from "onMyLocationChange" function which is inside onMyLocationChange function

Tags: android

I have an activity where it shows google map v2.
There , I have some Radio buttons and when I press the button "save" i want to save my current location.This button is in "onMyLocationChange" function.

The problem is that the latitude and longtitude are inside "onMyLocationChange" function..

The activity is :

```
public class selection extends FragmentActivity implements OnMyLocationChangeListener{

    GoogleMap googleMap;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.selection);

        // Getting Google Play availability status
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

        // Showing status
        if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ // Google Play Services are not available
            int requestCode = 10;
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
            dialog.show();

        }else {    // Google Play Services are available

            // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment of activity_main.xml
            SupportMapFragment mapFragment  = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

            // Getting GoogleMap object from the fragment
            googleMap = mapFragment.getMap();
            //set map type
            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

            // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            // Setting event handler for location change
            googleMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(this);


        RadioGroup rgViews = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg_views);

        rgViews.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                if(checkedId == R.id.rb_normal){
                    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                }else if(checkedId == R.id.rb_satellite){
                    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
                }else if(checkedId == R.id.rb_terrain){
                    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
                }
                else if(checkedId == R.id.save_location){

                    //here I want to save the location
                }
            }
        });
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
        TextView tvLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_location);

        // Getting latitude of the current location
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();

        // Getting longitude of the current location
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();

        // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        // Showing the current location in Google Map
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

        // Zoom in the Google Map
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));

        // Setting latitude and longitude in the TextView tv_location
        tvLocation.setText("Latitude:" +  latitude  + ", Longitude:"+ longitude );



    }



}
```

---------UPDATE---------------------------

```
else if(checkedId == R.id.save_location){

                    FileOutputStream fos;

                    File filePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/What_Where.txt");

                    try {
                        fos = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
                        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));
                        bw.write(latitude);
                        bw.write(longitude);
                        fos.flush();
                        fos.close();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        Log.e("Saving", e.getMessage(), e);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e("Saving", e.getMessage(), e);
                    }
```

it gives me at "bw.write" . the method is not applicable to arguments double.

Comment: @AwadKab:I am trying.I updated.It gives me an error in bw.write.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
bw.write(String.valueOf(latitude));
bw.write(String.valueOf(longitude));
```

**Edit**

Use this to write to file

```
File filePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/What_Where.txt");
    try {
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filePath, true));
        bw.append(String.valueOf(latitude));
        bw.append(String.valueOf(longitude));
        bw.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("Saving", e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Saving", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
```

This worked for me.

Hope this helped you.

Comment: :this works,but the file i save is empty.Am I doing wronf sth in saving?Or it has to do with declatring the variables as global and when i ask for them they don't have the values from location.getlongitude()...

Comment: :I think the problem is that inside "onCheckedChanged" i use the global variables which are empty.I need a way to use the variables inside "onMyLocationChange".Or i need to be able to call "onMyLocationChange" from "else if(checkedId == R.id.save_location){",but i can't think..

Comment: You can check that by `Log.d("lat",""+latitude);`. Put it in `else if(checkedId == R.id.save_location)` then check LogCat.

Answer (score 1):

```
    GoogleMap googleMap;
    double latitude=0.0;  <--- Declare as Global variable
    double longitude=0.0; <--- Declare as Global variable

public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {

        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        ...
}
```

Comment: :These variables inside "onCheckedChanged' function what value will they have?Will they extract the value from "onMyLocationChange"?

Comment: @ MAC:Thanks for your help.I upvoted.I found below the solution.